# Is there such thing as a client-side administration panel framework for RESTful resources?

Tags: node.js, rest, web, administration, sails.js

I've worked with Rails in the past, and I used [ActiveAdmin](http://www.activeadmin.info/) to make administration panels. I'm moving to Node and I'll be using Sails as a framework for a one-page app, and probably AngularJS on the client side, but there is still the issue of the administration panel.

Given that Sails pretty much setups all your resources for RESTful API access, I was thinking about using a client-based administration panel. But I don't know if such thing exists. If it doesn't I guess I'll be making my own, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I've yet to see anything worthwhile like this.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing and I found [ng-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin) which seems to suit what you're after - it's a client-side CRUD administration framework written in Angular and supporting REST APIs.

I've used it successfully in my own Sails based project and got it up and running very quickly. You can read more about it on [this blog post](http://marmelab.com/blog/2014/09/15/easy-backend-for-your-restful-api.html).

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such thing as an admin panel specifically tailored for sailsjs.

One of the admin panel's ive used for nodejs apps before is http://jedireza.github.io/drywall. Although its not client-side like you're asking.

Comment: I didn't mean specifically tailored for SailsJS, just to use with a RESTful API.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [admin-bro](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/admin-bro) package which aims to be something like rails-admin or ActiveAdmin but in Node.js. Currently it works with hapi and express frameworks.